# Ergodic theory regarding positive contraction operators on $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, ergodic-theory

I have been struggling for a long time trying to undersatnd the following theorem from infinite dimensional analysis for Aliprantis and Border.

I would be very grateful if one suggested a reference explaining this theorem better.[image]

Or even tell me what its name is.

Comment: You really need to be *much* more detailed.

Comment: @JohnB I would be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: The theorem is one among many others. You should tell us what is it that you don't understand.

Comment: @JohnB: he's asking for the name of the theorem, and for a reference. In what sense would knowing what he doesn't understand help you answer the question?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Without knowing what he knows, whatever the theorem is based on on that particular book, whatever is his problems with any specifics... etc, etc. But I have already replied: The theorem is one among many others, it is nonsense to ask for its name. It is of very simple nature also, but if you can add something please do reply to the OP. We encounter often people in operator theory thinking that they discovered something new when it is from the origins of ergodic theory.

Comment: @MartinArgerami could you help me ?

Comment: @JohnB could you help me ?